# nodejs cronjobs on multiple servers

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a group of nodejs servers as a backend (currently 3 servers).

I want to automate some tasks like sending a notification to all users on a specific time, and I'm planning to do this with cronjobs.

Because I have three servers, I'm worried the cronjobs will run 3 times, so all users will receive 3 notifications.

What is the best solution for this? The only solution I came up with so far is creating an extra nodejs server with only the cronjobs. Because this server will not get any visitors (load), it should not be a server with a high-CPU and high-memory count I guess?

Cronjobs are mostly database operations and sending FCM notifications. The fastest cronjob has to run every 5 minutes and needs to server almost 5 million accounts (inserting 5 million rows in a database table and sending 5 million notifications). Is this possible?

I'm hosting at the google cloud platform.

Comment: Do you want this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277797/managing-cron-jobs-across-multiple-servers

Comment: I believe the [Google Cloud Sub/Pub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) may meet your requirement